# MYSQL query between date behaviour

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, where-clause

I have a query as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM  tbl_invoice_header
WHERE Create_Date BETWEEN '2019-04-01' AND '2020-03-31'
AND Auth_Settle_Date >'2020-03-31';
```

I want to get all data between the date range but that was settled after 2020-03-31

It returns me a row where the Auth_Settle_Date=2020-03-31 14:24:36

Auth_Settle_Date is a date time columns so I guess that why it comes back

Which I guess is correct as it is after 2020-03-31 but not the functionality I was looking for

Based on previous comments if I use:
WHERE Create_Date BETWEEN '2019-04-01' AND '2020-03-31'
AND Auth_Settle_Date > '2020-03-31' ;

[image: it returns me 9 rows:]

If I use:
WHERE create_date >= '2019-03-01' AND create_date <'2020-04-01'
AND auth_settle_date >= '2020-04-01'

or

WHERE create_date >= '2019-03-01'   AND create_date <  '2020-04-01'
AND auth_settle_date >= '2020-03-31'  + INTERVAL 1 DAY

[image: it returns 10 records]

where as the actual correct query seems to be:

WHERE Create_Date BETWEEN '2019-04-01' AND '2020-03-31'
AND Auth_Settle_Date >= '2020-04-01'

So I guess it seems I will have to add a day outside the query to the to date before I pass it to the query, just seems a strange

[image: As this returns the correct 8 rows]

Answer (score 0):

> Is the only way to get the functionality to add 1 day to the date provided

Yes, that's the right way to do it. I would also recommend using half-open intervals on `create_date`, in case it has a time portion as well:

```
where create_date >= '2019-03-01' 
  and create_date <  '2020-04-01' 
  and auth_settle_date >= '2020-04-01'
```

Side note: I imagine that you meant `'2019-03-01'` rather than `'2019-04-01'` as the lower bound of the `create_date` interval (otherwise the query is somewhat non-sensical).

If the dates come from outside your code, as parameters to the query, you can add 1 day directly in the query:

```
where create_date >= :start_date
  and create_date <  :end_date + interval 1 day
  and auth_settle_date >= :end_date + interval 1 day
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `+ INtervall` for that

```
SELECT * FROM  tbl_invoice_header
WHERE Create_Date BETWEEN '2019-04-01' AND '2020-03-31'
AND Auth_Settle_Date > '2020-03-31' + INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```